SelfControl app for blocking websites blocks everything except some of the big adult video websites
I use SelfControl on Mac for blocking websites for a predetermined period of time.
It blocks everything except some very distractive websites, even though I entered all the domains and subdomains as required.
Any help would be appreciated.

From my recollection, you can change the macOS system’s time and date to a future date to get self control to unblock… then you should be able to set a new block within self control of just the sites you want

I use Cloudflare's "1.1.1.1" DNS service everywhere I can, and specifically its "1.1.1.1 for Families". I also use Pi-hole with some custom blocklists, but that's limited only to my network. Changing the DNS server you use isn't that hard, Pi-hole may be more robust but it is undoubtedly harder.
1.1.1.1 gives you a pretty damn reliable DNS service.
1.1.1.2 gives you that same DNS service but with Malware blocking (this is what I use).
1.1.1.3 gives you that same DNS service but with Malware and adult site blocking.
As I haven't used 1.1.1.3 I don't know how broad their filtering is.

I hadn't heard of that app before.  I block hundreds of sites for porn, malware, scams, and other things I dislike by putting in /etc/hosts lines like this:
0.0.0.0 pussysaga.com

I had read that the hosts file was "only used in single-user mode" but it isn't true.  Clicking on a URI from any domain in the file results in a 404, including the doubleclick ads dishonestly disguised as other domains.  That is the case today on 14.6.1 (23G93) and it has been the case for years.
If you want a temporary block, you could have a script that runs as root, renames /etc/hosts, and copies in a version with the blocked domains.  Then another script to put back the original, which could be triggered by at or after.
Warning: If you have a script that runs as root, make sure the permissions don't allow any other account to edit it!!!

A slight caveat: /etc/hosts doesn't handle large numbers of sites efficiently.   There are many blocklists available (for blocking malware sites, trackers, ad servers, etc.), some with millions of sites, and that slows down macOS very significantly.  (Or at least, it did — I haven't checked in recent versions.)  One alternative is to install and run a more efficient DNS server such as dnsmasq.

If it is slowing me down, I haven't noticed.  But I could delete 39,500 lines and see if I notice a speed-up.  I might also try dnsmasq again.  Last time I tried, there were problems.  There's also an option to point your resolver to an external filter like the cloudflare (https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/access-management/what-is-dns-filtering/) Jason mentioned.  In the past, I had BIND 9 running on a Mac I rarely used and had all our other devices using that.  With all DNS remaining within our local LAN, the speed-up was measurable.

I installed dnsmasq from HomeBrew, wrote a LaunchDaemon to run it, and configured it to delegate to CloudFlare's DNS, so all it does is resolve a few hosts on my LAN and the massive number of hosts that I blackhole, and everything else goes to CloudFlare to resolve as normal.

When I tried it, launchd didn't exist.  I just changed my resolv.conf to cloudflare's malware/porn address (it was previously on their 1.1.1.1 address).  So there's probably no need for my forty-thousand-line hosts file.  When I first connected to 1.1.1.1, they weren't blocking malware; they merely bragged at how fast they were.  Plus the bonus that they aren't NSA's biggest competitor.  Then again, I have no way of ensuring NSA isn't secretly running cloudfare.
